# Setting file encoding for org-mode ical export

Tags: emacs, gmail, icalendar, org-mode

I am exporting my agenda with

```lisp
(org-export-icalendar-combine-agenda-files)
```

and then loading the resulting file to a webserver from where my gmail calendar can read it.

My org-mode files are all utf-8 encoded and so is the ical file. However gmail eypects cp1252 (or so I think).

How can I set the file encoding during icalendar export?

Comment: Does your webserver report UTF-8 character encoding in the `Content-Type` HTTP response header?

Answer (score 3):

I tried to reproduce your case. When I exported my agenda files Emacs wrote them using iso-latin-1 encoding.

Then I put some Cyrillic text into my agenda files and then Emacs detected that it cannot write it with the default encoding and prompted for encoding to use.

I suggest that you check the variable `buffer-file-coding-system` and update it to cp1252 for agenda files.

Comment: That is exactly my problem -- agenda files are utf-8 encoded but the
exported file should be cp1252 encoded.

Comment: what is the value of buffer-file-coding-system variable in the org file buffer?

Comment: The local value of buffer-file-coding-system is utf-8. Therefore the
icalendar export file also has the same encoding. However I would like to have the exported file cp1252 encoded, so that Google Calendar would
read it correctly.

Comment: So set this variable to cp1252 and check how emacs will export the file

Comment: Are you talking about a file local variable? I have more than 50 agenda files which get exported through 'org-export-icalendar-combine-agenda-files'. So setting a variable in each agenda file seems impractical. What I am looking for is a way to export many utf-8 encoded agenda files to one cp1252 (latin-1) ical file.

Comment: You can set it in the file open hook for all org files

Comment: Well I do not want ot change the encoding of my agenda files for various reasons, not least for the encoding of German umlauts etc. and Latex export. My workflow is (should be): 
agenda files (utf-8) -> (org-export-icalendar-combine-agenda-files) -> export.ical (cp1252) -> ftp etc.